# Why can't I make my Css background image slide without f12?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, visual-web-developer

I am currently trying to make a website with CSS and Html, but I can't seem to make my background image slide and move. I us Visual studio code and I runned the code with google but it does not move but when I press f12 to debug, it moves?!
here is my code:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("I hacve a proper url but i don't wanna share it");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    animation: slide 1s linear infinite alternate; 
    }

    @keyframes slide {
        0% {
            background-position: -175% 0%;
        }
        100% {
            background-position: 300% 0%;
        }
    }

    .container {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

I tried asking chat gpt but I just got more confused